# How do you Implment fmt::Display for an array or slice of type T in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I implement `Display` for `[&MyStruct]`?

I've implemented `Display` for `MyStruct`,

```
impl fmt::Display for MyStruct {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, ..., ...)
    }
}
```

This issue I'm running into is when I return a `[&MyStruct]`, I can't print it,

```
11 |     println!("{}", sliceOfMyStructs);
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^ `[&MyStruct]` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `[&MyStruct]`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Display` for `&[&MyStruct]`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

What I've ready tried is (`MyStruct` is defined in my crate),

```
17 | impl fmt::Display for [MyStruct] {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl doesn't use types inside crate
   |
   = note: the impl does not reference only types defined in this crate
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

Comment: How do you expect Rust to know how you want to display the slice? Remember this is Display not Debug, and the display rules aren't just up to the compiler.

Comment: @SOFe read twice the question, the OP didn't talk blame std to not implement it